# How do I add these power series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

From the function $f(z)=\frac{z+9}{z^2-2z-3}$ I determined it can be rewritten as 
$f(z)=\frac{3}{z-3}+\frac{-2}{z+1}$.

The Taylor series for the partial fraction decomposition is expressed as
$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty -(\frac{z}{3})^n$ + $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}2(z)^n$

My best attempt at adding the series together is
$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+2}2(\frac{4z}{3})^n$. I derived this from the formula 
$f(x) + g(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (a_n + b_n)x^n$.

I don't remember this technique from Calculus II and III. My rationale is combine the $(-1)$ term to get $(-1)^{n+2}$ and rationalise $\frac{z}{3}$ with $z$ to get $\frac{4z}{3}$, raise it to the $^{nth}$ power and keep $2$ as a constant. Would I please be able to get further guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best to write the series as $\sum a_n z^n$ and $\sum b_n z^n$ to avoid arithmetic errors. Then we have
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n z^n + \sum_{n\geq 0} b_n z^n = \sum_{n\geq 0} (a_n+b_n) z^n
$$In particular,
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} -(1/3)^n z^n + \sum_{n\geq 0} 2(-1)^{n+1} z^n = \sum_{n\geq 0} \left(-(1/3)^n+2(-1)^{n+1} \right)z^n 
$$

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I assume the same response can be obtained by writing out the first few terms of the series and adding them together? I'm sure it would be more tedious than this method.

Comment: That can be a good strategy to see the general pattern, as long as you write the final result in sigma notation.